# Is there any way to disable current device zoom in java swt?

Tags: java, swt, zooming

The current device zoom value was fixed at 100 when creating an image in java swt after updating to windows 10 pro.
Is there any way to disable current device zoom?

Comment: A value of 100 already means no zooming. Please explain more clearly what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `swt.autoScale` system property to control SWT device scaling.

The JavaDoc in `DPIUtil` says the values of this property can be:

- `false`: The deviceZoom is set to 100%
- `integer`: The deviceZoom depends on the current display resolution, but only uses integer multiples of 100%. The detected native zoom is generally rounded down (e.g. at 150%, will use 100%), unless close to the next integer multiple (currently at 175%, will use 200%).
- `integer200`: like integer, but the maximal zoom level is 200%.
- `quarter`: The deviceZoom depends on the current display resolution, but only uses integer multiples of 25%. The detected native zoom is rounded to the closest permissible value.
- `exact`: uses the native zoom (with 1% as minimal step).
- `<value>`: uses the given integer value as the zoom level. The value is a percentage.

The current default is "integer200".