# How to draw image with device zoom set over 175%?

Tags: eclipse, swt, nebula

I want to display preview of a model before print on Windows10. My dialog window:

```
protected Control createDialogArea( Composite parent )
  {
    // some code

    preview = new PrintPreview( previewComp, SWT.NONE );

    GridData previewLayoutData = new GridData( GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true );
    previewLayoutData.widthHint = 450;
    previewLayoutData.heightHint = 600;

    preview.setLayoutData( previewLayoutData );

    // some code
    refreshPreview( true );
    setMessage( DialogMessage, IMessageProvider.INFORMATION );

    return parent;
  }
```

creating image buffer:

```
public void renderModelViewIntoImage(final ModelViewDataItem modelView, final boolean showOutlines, final boolean showGeometry, 
                                   final int width, final int height, boolean is3DHTMLImage, boolean fireCallback)
{
//some code

addAction(new RenderActionTask() {
  @Override
  public boolean doTask(GL gl)
  {
    // some code
    // Set width and height for camera.
    renderParams.getCamera().setWidth( width );
    renderParams.getCamera().setHeight( height );
    
    // Prepare PRINT scene - set bounds.
    Scene scene = scenes.get( SceneType.PRINT );
    scene.setBounds(width, height);

    // some code
    // Add PRINT scene to render parameters.
    renderParams.addScene(SceneType.PRINT, scene);

    // Get image (in ByteBuffer format) from PRINT scene.
    ByteBuffer imgBuffer = getModelViewImageData( gl, width, height );
    
    // some code
    
    // Notify viewerCallback about that model view was rendered.
    if(fireCallback)
      viewerCallback.mvRendered(modelView, imgBuffer, width, height, is3DHTMLImage);
      
    // Return - in false case, no refresh is required.
    return false;
  }
});
}
```

and creating ImageData:

```
public void mvRendered(ModelViewDataItem modelView, ByteBuffer imgBuffer, int width, int height, boolean is3DHTMLImage)
{
TreeDataItem mvTreeDataItem = modelView.getItem();
if(mvTreeDataItem == null)
  return;

if(something)
{
  // some code
} else
{
  ImageData swtImage = toSWTImage(imgBuffer, width, height);
  mvImageData.put(mvTreeDataItem, swtImage);
}

view.getParent().getDisplay().syncExec(new Runnable()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    view.mvRendered(modelView);
  }
});
}
```

While monitor zoom is set up to 150%, `org.eclipse.swt.internal.DPIUtil.getDeviceZoom()` returns `100` and everything works fine. But if zoom is set to 175% or higher, `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.drawImage(Image, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)` throws `SWT.ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT`. There is condition `int errX = src.x + src.width - b.width;` and `src.width` is always double of `b.width`, if device zoom = 200.

I really have no idea how to deal with this. Thanks for any idea!!

Update 5.4.2023, console error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4576)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4510)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4481)
        at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.drawImage(GC.java:939)
        at org.eclipse.nebula.paperclips.core.ImagePiece.paint(ImagePrint.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.nebula.paperclips.core.ScalePiece.paint(ScalePrint.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.nebula.paperclips.core.CompositePiece.paint(CompositePiece.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.nebula.paperclips.core.CompositePiece.paint(CompositePiece.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.nebula.paperclips.core.CompositePiece.paint(CompositePiece.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.nebula.paperclips.core.CompositePiece.paint(CompositePiece.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.nebula.paperclips.core.CompositePiece.paint(CompositePiece.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.nebula.paperclips.widgets.PrintPreview.paintPage(PrintPreview.java:460)
        at org.eclipse.nebula.paperclips.widgets.PrintPreview.paint(PrintPreview.java:426)
        at org.eclipse.nebula.paperclips.widgets.PrintPreview.access$0(PrintPreview.java:404)
        at org.eclipse.nebula.paperclips.widgets.PrintPreview$1.handleEvent(PrintPreview.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1055)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1064)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_PAINT(Composite.java:1564)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4825)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:348)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4778)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3545)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:636)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
        at com.transcat.tca3dn.viewer.rcp.Application.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
```

I did try scale image before drawing but did not help. There is some [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56745918/is-there-any-way-to-disable-current-device-zoom-in-java-swt) which might be helpful, but I am not probably understand, how to implement it.
I know there is Property to override high DPI scaling behavior by system, but that is not what I want.

Comment: You don't usually have to do anything to deal with the device zoom for images, although you can use `ImageDataProvider` to provide higher resolution images for higher zooms. But that error appears to be in Eclipse Nebula Paperclips - maybe that has an issue.

Comment: Hi @greg-449, thanks for your comment. This means I should avoid using paperclips? I have no control over it..

Comment: You can ask about the nebula controls on their github site - https://github.com/eclipse/nebula/issues and since it is open source even download the source to see if you can resolve the problem.

Comment: I am not gonna invest time into this. I see this behavior came with update from Eclipse3 to 4.10. I am gonna simply set scaling to 100% for now, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56745918/is-there-any-way-to-disable-current-device-zoom-in-java-swt)